Artifact Registry returning 404 for private Go module
I am using GCP Artifact Registry to store a private Go module. The module is automatically uploaded by Cloud Build when a git push is performed. The upload is successful each time, and I can see the resulting output in Artifact Registry.
Example:
Image showing module in Artifact Registry
The package path used in my program exactly matches what Artifact Registry shows:
Image showing Package path in Artifact Registry
When I try to run go mod tidy in a project that calls this private module on my local cli, a 404 error is returned from Artifact Registry. I am logged into Google Cloud on my local cli with an account that should have ample permissions to perform this - however I'd expect a 401, if it were lack of permissions.
Full output:
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/common
go: finding module for package australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/http
go: adminpanel imports
        australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/common: cannot find module providing package australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/common: unrecognized import path "australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/common": reading https://australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/common?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
<repeated for each module>

A simple go get returns a 404 error also:
$ go get australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs 
go: unrecognized import path "australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs": reading https://australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs?go-get=1: 404 Not Found

The golang in the program that is importing the above libraries looks like:
package main

import (
    <standard imports removed>

    commonhttp "australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/http"
)

<code removed>

Another example from another file in the program:
package main

import (
    <removed modules>

    config "australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/config"
    db "australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs/db"
)

The commonlibs structure is as follows:
$ tree .
.
├── cloudbuild.yaml
├── common
│   └── common.go
├── commonlibs.go
├── config
│   ├── config.go
│   └── structs.go
├── db
│   └── db.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── http
│   └── http.go
├── network
│   └── network.go
├── rabbitmq
│   └── rabbitmq.go
└── slack
    └── slack.go

This seems to match the suggested structure defined in the golang documentation.
In the commonlibs module the go.mod looks like:
module australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs

go 1.21.5

require (
        <removed list>
)

require (
        <removed list>
)

I have tried to resolve this by following the provided documentation on using private go modules from Artifact Repository however as the demonstration uses a path like example.com/module I'm not actually sure if I'm using the wrong path or URL to access my private module.
This question is similar to my issue, however I'm having the problem locally whereas that question did not.
I have tried with all forms and combinations of env variables, for example the following each on their own, all together. Tried refreshing auth tokens also as per the example, however no combination seems to help.
export GOOS=linux
export GONOSUMDB=australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/*
export GOPROXY=https://australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs,https://proxy.golang.org,direct
export GONOPROXY=github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools,australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/commonlibs
export GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go run github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools/cmd/auth@v0.1.0 refresh

So, I'm kinda stuck and stumped. As far as I know, this should work as presented.
I'm open to suggestions of things to try, or if I've made an obvious error (likely) please point it out :)

Did you GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go run github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-go-tools/cmd/auth@v0.1.0 add-locations --locations=australia-southeast1? I'd review the steps in Authenticate to Artifact Registry. I've never used Artifact Registry for Go modules but I'm inclined to try it as a result of your question.

I ran through the Quickstart and had no issues. Thinking about your use more, I wonder whether your issue is that you're using the Artifact Registry's URL (australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>) as part of your Module path?

@DazWilkin Yes, and I even touched on that in my question. I'm not sure what URL I should be using for the module path. The documentation only provides an example URL and doesn't outline what I should be using. I pieced this URL together from another example I found somewhere online.

@DazWilkin - Solved! I was totally misunderstanding how the module paths worked in this context - I changed the path to one not using the australia-southeast1-go.pkg.dev address and ensured I had the environment vars set - and it worked as expected.
Thank you for your comment!

I'm pleased to hear it! You're welcome
